# displaying file position in Proof General

Tags: emacs, proof-general

In Emacs/Proof General, I'm wondering if there is support for letting a proof assistant do either of the following things:

(1) Open a new window displaying a given file/character position;

(2) Display in either the goal or response windows a hyperlink that when clicked on will take the user to a given position in a file.